# Insert Into Access Table Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, sql-insert

I have a table I created and its purpose is to house a database of queries i have created over the years, I created a corresponding form to insert all the information but I am having trouble getting the code to work.

```
Private Sub cmd_go_Click()
Dim insertstring As String

    insertstring = "INSERT INTO KWTable (KW, Source, Code) VALUES (" & text_key.Value & "," & combo_source.Value & "," & text_code.Text & ");"

    DoCmd.RunSQL insertstring

End Sub
```

The three columns on the destination table are KW, Source, and Code the values being inserting into them are text_key (which are keywords that I type in so i can search them later when i need to reference certain things), combo_source.Value (which is a combo box with the list of databases where these codes and queries are saved, which i will select the right one when inserting into the table) and text_code ( which is the actual code itself of the query)

The code is supposed to insert the keywords (text) the source (combobox listing) and the code (text) into the KWTable. But when I click the add record button I get a "Runtime Error 424: Object Required" Error box and it has the whole insertstring line highlighted. I cannot troubleshoot where the error is. Any thoughts?

Comment: Those values are all text and you have no quotes. Even though this is for personal use, a parameter query may be a good idea, unless any of those fields are memo data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Option 1

As Remou said, you have no quotes around your text.  I've added some single quotes around each of your fields and added some line breaks for easier reading. Does that work?

```
Private Sub cmd_go_Click()
    Dim insertstring As String
    insertstring = "INSERT INTO KWTable (KW, Source, Code) VALUES ('" & _
                    text_key.Value & "','" & _
                    combo_source.Value & "','" & _
                    text_code & "');"
    DoCmd.RunSQL insertstring

End Sub
```

#### Option 2

I think this will handle storing single and double quotes in your table:

```
Private Sub cmd_go_Click()
Dim rst As recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("KWTable ")
With rst
     .addnew
     .fields("KW")=text_key.Value
     .fields("Source")=combo_source.Value
     .fields("Code")=text_code
     .update
 End with
 End sub
```

Comment: +1 But that is going to be unsafe, it is not impossible that the text to be inserted contains quotes, so you would need to use replace to escape them.

Comment: Good timing. I was right in the middle of editing my response to mention just that (especially since he's using it to store code). What if he skipped the insert query and used a recordset object with .update instead?

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not work, i added some more specifics of the function of this into the original post

Comment: Get rid of `text_code.Text`, it should be `text_code` or `text_code.value`. The .text property is only available when the control has focus.

Comment: I added a recordset option that I think should handle single and double quotes.

Comment: That code doesnt bring up an error, but when I open the table it is still blank.

Comment: Yes, I did. I even closed out access and reopened it

Comment: @user2119980 The code works for me. Have you tried entering the same data manually in your table? Have you tried substituting values, eg, `.fields("KW")="a"` Have you compacted and repaired recently?

Comment: Yes its still not working. How did you create the table, did you have to link it to the form at all?

Comment: No, I just tested the code. If you have the form bound to the table, there is no reason to run sql. The data will just be inserted into the bound fields.

Comment: Do you think it could possibly be the table I have setup?

Comment: That's easy enough to test. Rename your existing table to "zzzKWTable" as a backup. Then create a new "KWTable" with the 3 fields.  Keep all properties at their default values and see what happens when you run the code.

Comment: I have the 3 columns all set as text in the table, is there any other value I should assign them?

Comment: Nope. That all looks good to me. Are you sure you're actually running the code? You can test it by putting `Msgbox "Test"` in the function and see if it pops up when you think it should pop up.